# Mobx observe only specific objects in array

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

I have a store with events

```
export class EventStore {

    @observable
    events: Event[] = [];

    @action
    addEvent(event: Event) {
        this.events = [...this.events, event]
    };
};
```

My Event look like this :

```
export class Event{
   
   classType: string;
}
```

I want to observe change on `events` properties of store **BUT only of a specific** `classType`

For Eg :

I have Event with classType "AddToCart" and "Order", and I want to observe only "Order" added, removed from `events`

I want to use `import { observer } from "mobx-react"`

### Question :

Is there some magic trick to do in the EventStore or I have to handle it in my component (with some if) ?

### My unperfect solution

Meanwhile, I'm doing somehting like this :

```
  reaction(
            () => eventStore.lastEvent,
            event => {
                if (event.classType === "Order")
                    this.newEvent = { ...event }
            }
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `computed` property

```
    @computed
    get orderEvents() {
        // Add whatever filtering you want
        return this.events.filter(event => event.classType === 'Order')
    };
```

If you need to pass arguments you could you `computedFn` from `mobx-utils`:

```
    filteredEvents = computedFn(function (classType) {
        return this.events.filter(event => event.classType === classType)
    })
```

Note: don't use arrow functions as the `this` would be incorrect.

https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-utils#computedfn

https://mobx.js.org/refguide/computed-decorator.html#computeds-with-arguments

Comment: thanks for your answer. I upvote it, but this solution is not perfect for me, because I have to copy that for every classType

Comment: I've updated my answer with with `computedFn` where you can pass arguments. Is that better or still not what you need?